# Customize lookup isnull

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to customize isnull lookup to return both null and blank values and [django documentary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-lookups/) doesn't give enough inforamtion about how exactly it works. i need some help writing params and return value.

here is my code so far:

```
from django.db.models import Lookup


class IsNull(Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'isnull'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + lhs_params
        if rhs_params[0]:
            return '%s != %s and %s != %s' % (lhs, None, lhs, str()), params
        else:
            return '%s == %s or %s == %s' % (lhs, None, lhs, str()), params

# User.objects.filter(first_name__is_null=True)
```

error:

```
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "LIMIT": syntax error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was in the built in isnull lookup.

customized:

```
import warnings

from django.db.models import Field
from django.db.models.lookups import BuiltinLookup
from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango40Warning


@Field.register_lookup
class IsNull(BuiltinLookup):
    lookup_name = 'isnull'
    prepare_rhs = False

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        if not isinstance(self.rhs, bool):
            # When the deprecation ends, replace with:
            # raise ValueError(
            #     'The QuerySet value for an isnull lookup must be True or '
            #     'False.'
            # )
            warnings.warn(
                'Using a non-boolean value for an isnull lookup is '
                'deprecated, use True or False instead.',
                RemovedInDjango40Warning,
            )
        sql, params = compiler.compile(self.lhs)
        if self.rhs:
            # * return either null or blank
            return "%s IS NULL OR %s IS ''" % (sql, sql), params
        else:
            # * return neither null nor blank
            return "%s IS NOT NULL AND %s IS NOT ''" % (sql, sql), params
```

original:

```
@Field.register_lookup
class IsNull(BuiltinLookup):
    lookup_name = 'isnull'
    prepare_rhs = False

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        if not isinstance(self.rhs, bool):
            # When the deprecation ends, replace with:
            # raise ValueError(
            #     'The QuerySet value for an isnull lookup must be True or '
            #     'False.'
            # )
            warnings.warn(
                'Using a non-boolean value for an isnull lookup is '
                'deprecated, use True or False instead.',
                RemovedInDjango40Warning,
            )
        sql, params = compiler.compile(self.lhs)
        if self.rhs:
            return "%s IS NULL" % sql, params
        else:
            return "%s IS NOT NULL" % sql, params
```